# AutoSuggestBox with Template10 doesn't suggest anything

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, template10

I'm currently learning programming in C# and XAML and also using the MVVM. I have checked the official `AutoSuggestBox` sample from Microsoft. I looked at the code and tried to achieve the same thing with Template 10 but with no luck. No suggestions pop up.

**MainPage.XML**:

```
<AutoSuggestBox RelativePanel.Below="stateTextBox"
                x:Name="asb"
                PlaceholderText="Type a name (e.g. John)"
                DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                TextMemberPath="DisplayName"
                QueryIcon="Find"
                Margin="0,24,0,24"
                MinWidth="296"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                TextChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.FilterUsuals}"
                QuerySubmitted="{x:Bind ViewModel.ProcessQuery}"
                SuggestionChosen="{x:Bind ViewModel.ProcessChoice}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
                />
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**:

```
Contact _Contact = default(Contact);
public Contact Contact { get { return _Contact; } set { Set(ref _Contact, value); } }

public void FilterUsuals(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // We only want to get results when it was a user typing,
    // otherwise we assume the value got filled in by TextMemberPath
    // or the handler for SuggestionChosen
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
    {
        var matchingContacts = ContactSampleDataSource.GetMatchingContacts(sender.Text);

        sender.ItemsSource = matchingContacts.ToList();
    }
}

public void ProcessQuery(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

public void ProcessChoice(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    var contact = (Contact)args.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest handling UI events in your page's code-behind in order to keep the UI separate from the view-model.

Here's an example, with some extras removed to keep it simple:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="FruitsSuggestion"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.FruitSuggestions, Mode=OneWay}"                    PlaceholderText="Search"
                QueryIcon="Find"
                QuerySubmitted="FruitsSuggestion_QuerySubmitted"
                Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Query, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void FruitsSuggestion_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    ViewModel.Filter();
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
private string _query = default(string);
public string Query { get => _query; set => Set(ref _query, value); }

private List<string> _allFruits = new List<string>
{
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Plum",
    "Peach",
    "Pineapple"
};
private ObservableCollection<string> _fruitSuggestions = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> FruitSuggestions => _fruitSuggestions;

public void Filter()
{
    FruitSuggestions.Clear();
    FruitSuggestions.AddRange(from fruit in _allFruits
                              where fruit.Contains(Query)
                              select fruit);
}
```

When you run the `Filter` method, it will update the `ObservableCollection`, which will in turn update the suggested items in your `AutoSuggestBox`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I solved the problem now :)